# I reverted a commit by mistake - how to recover changes

Tags: git, github

I made a lot of changes to a project of mine, so I wanted to push the changes to a temporary branch just in case, but I pushed to the main one instead. I try to revert with something like

```
git push -f origin last_commit_before_changes:master
```

I wasn't expecting it to make changes locally, so by mistake I overwritten everything (including my backup.....) and I had not already pushed to the correct branch. Is it possible to fix this stupid mistake? Is the diff still stored somewhere? It is not shown when I do `git log`.

You can tell I'm not very experienced with Git and I know I made multiple mistakes leading to this situation.

Comment: Just to note that it's typically safer to use `git revert` to revert a change, unless there's a specific reason you want to also remove it from history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push -f origin last_commit_before_changes:master
```

This will just do: forcefully update the remote remote `master` with the local branch `last_commit_before_changes`.

Assuming that your local master was up-to-date, you can just do:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

If your master was behind (since you’re working with others) then just do this command and ask all coworkers to do it (note no option `-f`):

```
git push origin master
```

This should restore everything.

A more complex way is to check logs from:

```
git reflog
```

And find there what was the hash of `origin/master` before the forceful push.

Then this should fix it:

```
git push -f origin <hash found in reflog>:master
```

Note that most commands in `git` are nondestructive. Old commits are there just hidden for the UI. Git retains everything for some long period or until you enforce garbage collection.